# Refrigerating warm potato salad 13 hours after dinner

Tags: food-safety

I prepared warm potato salad last night for dinner. We finished around 7:00 pm and I forgot to refrigerate it until 8:30 this am. Therefore, it was left out for approx. 13 and1/2 hours. When I felt it this am; it wasn't warm and actually a little on the cool side. My AC was turned down low so the house was around 63- 67 degrees all night.

So, Is it ok to eat or should I throw it out due to bacteria and/or etc..??

Please let me know as soon as you can....now would be good...just kidding kinda... I'm just really worried because I have a son that loves it and I need to know whether we will be having that potato salad for dinner tonight or a bunch of guilt-ridden banana splits? ....hmmmm? Tough decision...

Thank you to whoever answers... It will be greatly appreciated!!   :•)  8•)

Answer (score 3):

Throw it away! Warm potato salad is a breeding ground for all sorts of food-borne illnesses, and 13+ hours is far too long at room temperature.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!! I'm throwing it out right now...you are a lifesaver, literally!!!! ...  :)  8•)

Comment: I think you get credit for asking the question @JeanBostick. By the way there are several previous questions on this site about food safety which give useful guidelines which have more detailed answers than mine and are well worth reading.